# weird find command doing hard I/O operations and freeze my pc

Tags: linux

I've noticed than many times my laptop freezes, checking the possible causes I found than it happens exactly when my disk is doing heavy work...now using `iotop` I found this:

```
29620 idle nobody     97.48 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % find / -ignore_readdir_race ( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o~\|\(^/sfs$\)\|\(^/media$\)\|\(^/var/lib/schroot/mount$\) ) -prune -o -print0
```

this happens automatically, I don't know what app or service is running this command and really I can't understand so much about this...

1. What does this command mean and what launches it?
2. is it possible limit the disk write or avoid decrease the performance in my system? Since a few months I notice than my machine constantly freezes for I/O from the disk, my machine isn't old (i5 6gb ram) and it's weird this behaviour (it worked perfectly before)

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this question on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/437218/strange-processes-on-server-consume-cpu).

Comment: Next time it's running, use `ps -ef` to find its parent process (ppid). Might have to do with the database used by locate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a file `/etc/updatedb.conf` which' contents match with that `find` commands argument (i.e. the `find` parameters are set based on that file).

This is a partial command of the update of the update of the database used by `locate`/`mlocate` and triggered on a daily basis fron `cron` or (on my machine) from `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`

The command is most likely postponed if the machine is running of the battery, so there might not be an exact recurring time for this to occur.

In my `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate` there is test for the availability of `ionice`:

```
# See ionice(1)
if [ -x /usr/bin/ionice ] &&
    /usr/bin/ionice -c3 true 2>/dev/null; then
    IONICE="/usr/bin/ionice -c3"
fi
```

and if you haven't got that installed, or don't have those lines, you might want to expiriment installing/adding/playing with the parameters and see if that solves the freezing.

Comment: thanks Anthon..I've accepted your answer, unfortunately seems than there are more process doing heavy I/O in my disk and constantly this freeze, this is recent problem and maybe can be an error with the disk or memory, exist some utility like cpulimit for I/O operations for avoiding high intensive I/O operations than can freeze my OS???..

Comment: @user1050817 I recommend you start with looking at your `/var/log/syslog` or other system log for IO errors on your disc. And use `smartctl -x /dev/sdXY` on your drive(s). I don't know about limiting IO, that is something the kernel decides upon and I am not sure you can control that.

Comment: That you see `find` is running might be because it triggers reading of bad sectors.